# Why Mocha couldn't find module? Cannot find module 'expect.js'

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I run `mocha test` but got error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'expect.js'
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "new-restexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "PORT=3007 ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test -R spec"
  },
  "author": "Richard Rublev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "expect": "^25.3.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "standard": "^14.3.3",
    "superagent": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.36",
    "mongoskin": "^2.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

I looked with tree -d

```
│   ├── expect
│   │   ├── build
│   │   │   └── ts3.4
│   │   ├── build-es5
│   │   └── node_modules
│   │       ├── ansi-styles
│   │       ├── color-convert
│   │       └── color-name
```

Why is expect not recognized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`expect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect) and [`expect.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect.js) are two different packages.

The first one is installed, but you are trying to use the second one.

In case `expect.js` is needed, simply run `npm install expect.js` and you should be sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use expect you have to install an assertion library that allows you to it, installing directly expect didn't worked for me, i installed chai when i had a similar issue. Install it like this:

```
npm i --save-dev chai
```

Then import in the next manner and use like this:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

expect(numbers).to.be.an('array').that.includes(2);
```

In the package.json scripts:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I need this one, https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect.js.

Comment: @RichardRublev I had a similar issue, at the end i used chai, chai is expect works very much in the same way that expect.js